# Use sde-external-9.14.0-2022-10-25-lin to get region pinball error : Freepages: Out of memory

Tags: performance, out-of-memory, intel

I want to use sde to get region pinball from the whole pinball which is from SPEC2006 473case，but I find a error. Its output is as following:

```
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
Freepages: Out of memory
......
```

I have tested the sde-external-9.14.0-2022-10-25-lin.tar.xz,sde-external-8.69.1-2021-07-18-lin.tar.bz2 and sde-external-9.21.1-2023-04-24-lin.tar.xz, they have the same problem.

473perfwarmup100000length100000.473perfwarmup100000length100000_3349724.pinpoints.in.csv:
cluster 323 from slice 75,0,123,87,387,0.00219

473perfwarmup100000length100000.473perfwarmup100000length100000_3349724.0.result:

```
-- start of image-load-log --------------------------------------- 
Loading /home/zgcc/Pinball/473perfwarmup100000length100000/run/astarperf(0x000400000:0x0004e8017)
preloaded_image: 1 1  0x000000000 /home/f/Pinball/473perfwarmup100000length100000/run/astarperf
-- end of image-load-log ----------------------------------------- 
copy_images: 0
inscount: 14298436387
OSTid: 3349724
log_entries: 115156
ended_before_sc: 0
num_logged_true_dependencies (RAW): 0
num_logged_false_dependencies (WAR/WAW): 0
num_signals 0
num_syscalls: 1787
ip_type: init_pc: 0x000401490
ip_type:last_pc: 0x000432986
restore_text_pc: 1
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00049f318
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048c683
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000435373
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048ba99
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00046c184
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000441405
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048bac4
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004896e7
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00049f3c5
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00043544a
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000417f76
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a48ba
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048bbf7
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00040bfc4
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048a4a8
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000411457
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00041206f
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a19aa
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a31c0
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048ed83
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00046c454
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a325a
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a1a53
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a1a5c
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a1a76
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a1a7e
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048edf0
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a1ac0
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048c9ff
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00043570a
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048a623
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000461cca
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a1b41
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a1b51
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048d74a
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048d79a
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048c091
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048a89a
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048909b
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048a8c2
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00046d3b6
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004a1da4
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00041491d
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000431ec7
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000401107
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00040111f
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000401126
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00046d545
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00046bd71
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004011b0
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004011cf
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00041ab17
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00041ab1f
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004404f5
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00041abb8
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00048c3e1
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000410f70
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00041abdc
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00046bedf
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000484bf2
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000430970
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000411123
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000401490
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x0004014b5
```

473perfwarmup100000length100000.473perfwarmup100000length100000_3349724.relog.txt:

```
Enabled messages [UnixVersion()] 55  info: Informational messages (enabled by default)
Logger finished sanity check 
Logger first configuration phase completed 
Region selector activated 
Pinball basename: whole_program.473perfwarmup100000length100000/473perfwarmup100000length100000.473perfwarmup100000length100000_3349724
Relog set log:fat flag 
Replaying on 'Linux', recorded on 'Linux'
Found VDSO in page 0x7ffedd345000
[0] Pinball basename: /home/jingge/mnt/tools/sde/tmp/473perfwarmup100000length100000.473perfwarmup100000length100000_3349724.pp/473perfwarmup100000length100000.473perfwarmup100000length100000_3349724
Relogging run, will wait for Ok signal from replayer
Preloaded images: 1
Setting image replay mode in Pin.
[0] Started logging thread OSPid: 49448 OSTid: 49448
[0] Started Replaying thread OSPid: 49448 OSTid: 49448 PIN tid 0
[0] Restoring initial pages
Replay preloaded 1 images 
Replay preloaded image: /home/zgcc/Pinball/473perfwarmup100000length100000/run/astarperf Image index: 0
Loading /home/zgcc/Pinball/473perfwarmup100000length100000/run/astarperf(0x000400000:0x0004e8016)
[0] Thread replayer initialized
[0] Mapping stack address, pin tid 0
[0] All threads were created, ready to replay 
[0] Restoring Initial checkpoint before PC:0x000401490 ctxt: 0x14f116f56dc0
[0] Replayer ThreadStart Initial IP: 0x000401490
[0] region-start
[0] + RECEIVED AND PROCESSED START event: ip:0x000401437 time:Wed Jun  7 16:37:33 2023
[0] Stopping all threads - processing controller event
[0] Stopping all threads succeeded
[0] + STARTING NEW REGION at: ip:0x00040144a time:Wed Jun  7 16:37:33 2023
[0] iregion SetRegionName final 14298436386 region_end 387 region id 123 length 300 warm len 0 prolog len 0 epi len 0 slice size 14298436299 start icount 87
[0] Region has 1 existing threads(s)
[0] SyncThreads clear pending event 
[0] Resuming all threads - complied processing controller event
[0] InitRegion : 0
[0] region-end
[0] + RECEIVED STOP event: icount: 296 time:Wed Jun  7 16:37:33 2023
[0] Stopping all threads - processing controller event
[0] Stopping all threads succeeded
[0] EndRegion called for pp_id: 0
[0] End of Region at icount: 297
[0] Closing global resources.
[0] RemoveVsyscallFromRanges: removed pages: 0
[0] Wrote address ranges: pagecount: 89438. Logged text pages count:89438 Logged data pages count:0 (total logged pages:89438)
[0] SUCCESSFULLY CLOSED ALL TRACE FILES AT REGION END.
[0] FinishRegion reseting all thread icounts 
[0] SyncThreads clear pending event 
[0] Resuming all threads - complied processing controller event
[0] Replayer End of thread reached: 14298436386 final count: 14298436386
[0] Wait for all threads to finish 
[0] Finished replaying thread OSPid: 49448 OSTid: 49448, 14298436386 instructions
[0] ThreadFini in Replayer with status 0
[0] ThreadFini: logger thread at 0x14f116f60408
[0] EndRegion called for pp_id: 0
Process exit with status 0
Closing message file
```

473perfwarmup100000length100000.473perfwarmup100000length100000_3349724_t0r123_warmup0_prolog0_region300_epilog0_123_0-00219.0.result:

-- start of image-load-log ---------------------------------------

```
Loading /home/zgcc/Pinball/473perfwarmup100000length100000/run/astarperf(0x000400000:0x0004e8016)
preloaded_image: 1 1  0x000000000 0x000000000 0x000000000 0x000000000 /home/zgcc/Pinball/473perfwarmup100000length100000/run/astarperf
end of image-load-log ----------------------------------------- 
OSTid: 49448
log_entries: 0
ended_before_sc: 0
num_logged_true_dependencies (RAW): 0
num_logged_false_dependencies (WAR/WAW): 0
num_signals 0
num_syscalls: 0
inscount: 297
ip_type:last_pc: 0x00043544a
internal_repcount: 0
internal_last_repcount: 0
ip_type: init_pc: 0x000401633
restore_text_pc: 1
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000435373
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000401633
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00043544a
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000401844
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000401107
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x00040111f
ip_entry:restoretext_pc: 0x000401126
```

Thank you very much.